# Scrape the table rows according to the column name

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract the table but the issue is that all the table in that [Website](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_defunct_airlines_of_Africa) each columns has different position in each table. It is possible to scrape according to the column name and then all row of that columns

Here is an example:
[image: Here is the first table]
[image: Here is the 2nd table]

as you can see all the columns has different position in tables

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class LiSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'li'
    allowed_domains = ['en.wikipedia.org']
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_defunct_airlines_of_the_Americas',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_defunct_airlines_of_Asia',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_defunct_airlines_of_Europe',
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_defunct_airlines_of_Oceania']

    rules = (
      
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_xpaths='//div[text() = "Main article: "]/a'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
           for data in response.xpath('//table[@class="wikitable sortable"]/tbody/tr'):
            yield{
                'Airline': data.xpath('./td[1]/a/text()').get(),
                'IATA': data.xpath('./td[2]/text()').get(),
                'ICAO': data.xpath('./td[3]/text()').get(),
                'Image': data.xpath('./td[position() = count(//th[contains(.,"Image")]/following-sibling::th)+2]]/a/@href').get(),
                'Callsign': data.xpath('./td[5]/text()').get(),
                'Commensed Operations': data.xpath('./td[6]/text()').get(),
                'Ceased Operations': data.xpath('./td[7]/text()').get(),
                'Notes': data.xpath('./td[8]/text()').get(),
            }
```

Comment: Try this way `df = pd.read_html(link, match="Airline")[0]` to get the table containing `Airline` in it's header.

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas.
Try this:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_defunct_airlines_of_Africa")
```

You'll get list of data frames

Comment: But I want to arrange all columns in sequence

Comment: When you'll get a table in pandas.DataFrame type you can do what you want

Comment: How can i only get tables in pandas frame. Above code will get the all data from that webpage but I just want table